# Setting a different picture for each Messages account

Tags: messages, icon

I have recently retired Adium in favor of Apple's own Messages app, because it makes my life easier in some ways (especially ever since getting an iPhone). However, there is one feature that Adium had which Messages apparently does not - the ability to set a different user icon on each account.

I like having some of my accounts have a different picture for various reasons (for example, having a more professional icon on my work account and a more fun one on my personal account); is there any way to get this functionality back, without having to use both Adium *and* Messages?

Comment: What are the different accounts?

Comment: @SteppingHat Not that it should matter, but I have one AIM, two Jabber, and one iCloud/iMessage.

Answer (score 1):

I've researched it a bit and tinkered with the messages application myself because I too use multiple accounts and thought a different picture would actually be great for my uses.

However to my disappointment, this isn't a possibility. You can only change your account picture as a one-for-everything picture in `Messages -> Change My Picture...` which is a shame really.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I guess we can all just start spamming Apple with a feature request and hope they'll fix it at some point in Yosemite. :/